# HUBBLE EXPANSION: scale factor change

Tags: cosmology

If the FRLW scale factor is 1 now, was it smaller or larger  at earlier times? Does it asymptotically approach zero or infinity as you look back closer to the big bang?

Or what?

ty!

Comment: It was smaller in the past. By definition the Big Bang is the time at which it goes to zero.

Answer (score 3):

The universe is expanding, so $a$ is getting larger. In the past it was smaller. Extrapolating back to a classical, General Relativistic big bang, it goes to zero.